# Arithmetic mean of a sequence in normed vector spaces

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, means

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in a normed vector space $X$. Is it possible to calculate the sequence of arithmetic means of $x_n$ as follows: $$a_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}.$$ 
or, under which conditions the above formula is valid?

Comment: Cesaro means I think would be.

Comment: Is it meaningful for all normed vector spaces?

Comment: you can add elements and you can multiply by constant, so why not?

Comment: Are you sure of the formulation of your question ? If you are asking whether you can multiply the scalar $\frac 1n$ by the vector $x_1+\cdots+x_n$, then the answer is yes ! And the structure of normed vector space is not necessary for doing so : any (real or complex) vector space would do the job.

Comment: Actually I wondered if $(a_n)$ preserves the limit when $(x_n)$ is convergent. I guess the answer is Yes.

Comment: You have to assume that $x_n$ converges to $x$ in $X$.